# ASP.Net Vs. ASP

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp-classic

Ten years ago or so I built a small web site in ASP. I basically wrote it in a text editor and uploaded the files to a web server. I then didn't program anything for the web for a while and now I work in Visual Studio 2012 in C#, VB.Net and ASP.Net. The questions is, is the old ASP I originally worked in still a viable alternative for creating web sites? Would a professional even consider it or has the industry completely moved away from it?

I ask because a large project is going to be started this year for the small company I work for. It looks like it is going to be handed to someone who's skill-set has never moved past the old ASP. He does not do a lot of programming, but is capable at what he does. It seems wrong to me, but I don't know enough about the industry outside my little world to make an argument against it.

Thanks.

Comment: People still maintain and extend existing Classic ASP sites, but no one does anything new there. Think in terms of not only building this site, but also finding a developer to maintain it a few years down the road. Classic ASP developers just won't exist anymore.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. You might be able to get help on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: One of my colleagues [sent me this link](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57643/focus=57918) in an email the other day, a conversation between Linus Torvalds and Dmitry Kakurin which was very interesting (though not about ASP.NET and Classic ASP, it does share the context to a degree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really believe that anyone that has kept up with any sort of industry trends would do green field dev in Classic ASP. Using classic ASP just closes off a lot of avenues and makes life harder. Try finding good classic ASP developers? It's a nightmare. There is less and less resources available to help develop. Had the same issues and I took a department over and implemented MVC and customers are far happier. All the things you get for free like validation etc makes for far better apps. Can do TDD easily in MVC and not easily done in Classic ASP. Routing, JSON, clean separation of concerns, loose coupling, modern ORM availability, good IDE, just so many benefits of moving to a modern language.

You can write classic ASP reasonably well but most Classic ASP code I have ever seen looks like Spaghetti.

Comment: Thanks. This helps confirm what I assumed. I'll see if I can head this project in the right direction.

Comment: Just not looking in the right places ;)

Answer (score 3):

I personally do a lot of *legacy* (there's something to that term) ASP work to support *aging* infrastructure until it is ultimately *replaced* (parallel work) by ASP.Net.

While you will find/rediscover "hidden gems" like the *now-sexy-again* "javascript on the server-side" (yes, you can do Javascript in classic ASP) and yes, you [can handle JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in classic ASP, the term "legacy" is, IMHO, really all there is to it.

Dev support for it today, is likely out of *necessity* more than anything. Considering it for *new* development should be the question hard to argue ***for***. Translated to a business question - would you *invest new money and resources* on *outdated* infrastructure?

For your dev - it's not going to be a "cakewalk" but he/she will find things still familiar (and much better). Moving from `VBScript` (classic asp) to `VB.Net` will likely be the path of least resistance.

The "funny" thing about being "used" to ASP is that it might actually allow your dev to "skip" ASP.Net `WebForms` and "leapfrog" to `MVC` and/or [`WebPages` and `Razor`](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) - re: it's more "bare metal" stuff like it was in classic ASP!

HTH....

Comment: Thanks. This helps confirm what I assumed. I'll see if I can head this project in the right direction.